# How do I get tcolorbox to start at the current location

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using tcolorbox to create framed text in a multicols environment. Even though my frame is defined as breakable LaTeX tries to start frames at the top of a column which can result in very awkward formatting. You can see an example of this in the following picture.

[image]

What I would like is for the framed section to start in the first column, and thus avoid the large amount of whitespace. Is there a setting I can use for this?

Here is the source for my minimal example.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}\tcbuselibrary{breakable}\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{frameddbox}[2][]{
    enhanced,  
    breakable,
    before upper={\parindent15pt}

}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{section 1}

\subsection{sub section 1}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{frameddbox}

\subsection{framed subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{frameddbox}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{subsection 2}

\lipsum[4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your code on my updated TeXLive 2018 distribution, I get a very different output. In particular, the box (which I would not call `etoolbox` BTW) starts in the left column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've corrected the title and I'll try getting a more recent TeXLive environment.